# wsdl2java failes for Exchange 2010 Autodiscover WebService

Tags: apache-axis, exchangewebservices

I want to create WebService client classes for using Autodiscover WebService at Exchange 2010.

I'm very happy if someone can help me!!!!

**I use the following command:**

```
wsdl2java -d xmlbeans -uri Services.wsdl -o client -u -sn ExchangeAutodiscoverService -pn ExchangeAutodiscoverSoapPort
```

**I get the following exceptions:**

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException:
>   org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: org.apache.ax
>   is2.wsdl.databinding.UnmatchedTypeException: No type was mapped to the
>   name GetUserSettingsRequestMessage with namespace
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/ exchange/2010/Autodiscover
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:293)
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24) Caused by: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException:
>   org.apache.axis2.wsdl.databinding.UnmatchedTypeException: No type was
>   mapped to the name GetUserSettingsRequestMessage with namespace
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.emitter.AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.emitStub(AxisServiceBasedMultiLanguageEmitter.java:537)
>           at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.generate(CodeGenerationEngine.java:282)
>           ... 2 more

**This is Services.wsdl:**

```wsdl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
    <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover/Imports">
      <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover" location="messages.xsd" />
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="GetUserSettingsRequestMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetUserSettingsRequestMessage" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetUserSettingsRequestMessage_Headers">
    <wsdl:part name="RequestedServerVersion" element="tns:RequestedServerVersion" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetUserSettingsResponseMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetUserSettingsResponseMessage" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="GetUserSettingsResponseMessage_Headers">
    <wsdl:part name="ServerVersionInfo" element="tns:ServerVersionInfo" />
  </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="Autodiscover">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetUserSettings">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover/Autodiscover/GetUserSettings" name="GetUserSettingsRequestMessage" message="tns:GetUserSettingsRequestMessage" />
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover/Autodiscover/GetUserSettingsResponse" name="GetUserSettingsResponseMessage" message="tns:GetUserSettingsResponseMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="DefaultBinding_Autodiscover" type="tns:Autodiscover">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetUserSettings">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover/Autodiscover/GetUserSettings" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input name="GetUserSettingsRequestMessage">
        <soap:header message="tns:GetUserSettingsRequestMessage_Headers" part="RequestedServerVersion" use="literal" />
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="GetUserSettingsResponseMessage">
        <soap:header message="tns:GetUserSettingsResponseMessage_Headers" part="ServerVersionInfo" use="literal" />
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="ExchangeAutodiscoverService">
    <wsdl:port name="ExchangeAutodiscoverSoapPort" binding="tns:DefaultBinding_Autodiscover">
        <soap:address location="https://vm-bs-xchg2010/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.svc"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>    
</wsdl:definitions>
```

**This is the messages.xsd:**

```xsd
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="GetUserSettingsRequestMessage">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Request" nillable="true" type="tns:GetUserSettingsRequest" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="GetUserSettingsRequest">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="tns:AutodiscoverRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Users" nillable="true" type="tns:Users" />
          <xs:element name="RequestedSettings" nillable="true" type="tns:RequestedSettings" />
          <xs:element name="RequestedVersion" nillable="true" type="tns:ExchangeVersion" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="GetUserSettingsRequest" nillable="true" type="tns:GetUserSettingsRequest" />
  <xs:complexType name="AutodiscoverRequest">
    <xs:sequence />
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="AutodiscoverRequest" nillable="true" type="tns:AutodiscoverRequest" />
  <xs:complexType name="Users">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="User" nillable="true" type="tns:User" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="Users" nillable="true" type="tns:Users" />
  <xs:complexType name="User">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Mailbox" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="User" nillable="true" type="tns:User" />
  <xs:complexType name="RequestedSettings">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Setting" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="RequestedSettings" nillable="true" type="tns:RequestedSettings" />
  <xs:simpleType name="ExchangeVersion">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Exchange2010" />
      <xs:enumeration value="Exchange2010_SP1" />
      <xs:enumeration value="Exchange2010_SP2" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="RequestedServerVersion">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="tns:ExchangeVersion" />
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="GetUserSettingsResponseMessage">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Response" nillable="true" type="tns:GetUserSettingsResponse" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="GetUserSettingsResponse">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="tns:AutodiscoverResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UserResponses" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfUserResponse" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="GetUserSettingsResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:GetUserSettingsResponse" />
  <xs:complexType name="AutodiscoverResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ErrorCode" type="tns:ErrorCode" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ErrorMessage" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="AutodiscoverResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:AutodiscoverResponse" />
  <xs:simpleType name="ErrorCode">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="NoError" />
      <xs:enumeration value="RedirectAddress" />
      <xs:enumeration value="RedirectUrl" />
      <xs:enumeration value="InvalidUser" />
      <xs:enumeration value="InvalidRequest" />
      <xs:enumeration value="InvalidSetting" />
      <xs:enumeration value="SettingIsNotAvailable" />
      <xs:enumeration value="ServerBusy" />
      <xs:enumeration value="InvalidDomain" />
      <xs:enumeration value="NotFederated" />
      <xs:enumeration value="InternalServerError" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="ErrorCode" nillable="true" type="tns:ErrorCode" />
  <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfUserResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="UserResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:UserResponse" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="ArrayOfUserResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfUserResponse" />
  <xs:complexType name="UserResponse">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="tns:AutodiscoverResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RedirectTarget" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UserSettingErrors" nillable="true" type="tns:UserSettingErrors" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="UserSettings" nillable="true" type="tns:UserSettings" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="UserResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:UserResponse" />
  <xs:complexType name="UserSettingErrors">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="UserSettingError" nillable="true" type="tns:UserSettingError" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="UserSettingErrors" nillable="true" type="tns:UserSettingErrors" />
  <xs:complexType name="UserSettingError">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ErrorCode" type="tns:ErrorCode" />
      <xs:element name="ErrorMessage" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="SettingName" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="UserSettingError" nillable="true" type="tns:UserSettingError" />
  <xs:complexType name="UserSettings">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="UserSetting" nillable="true" type="tns:UserSetting" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="UserSettings" nillable="true" type="tns:UserSettings" />
  <xs:complexType name="UserSetting">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Name" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="UserSetting" nillable="true" type="tns:UserSetting" />
  <xs:complexType name="ProtocolConnectionCollectionSetting">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="tns:UserSetting">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="ProtocolConnections" nillable="true" type="tns:ProtocolConnections" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="ProtocolConnectionCollectionSetting" nillable="true" type="tns:ProtocolConnectionCollectionSetting" />
  <xs:complexType name="ProtocolConnections">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ProtocolConnection" nillable="true" type="tns:ProtocolConnection" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="ProtocolConnections" nillable="true" type="tns:ProtocolConnections" />
  <xs:complexType name="ProtocolConnection">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Hostname" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="Port" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element name="EncryptionMethod" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="ProtocolConnection" nillable="true" type="tns:ProtocolConnection" />
  <xs:complexType name="StringSetting">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="tns:UserSetting">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Value" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="StringSetting" nillable="true" type="tns:StringSetting" />
  <xs:complexType name="WebClientUrlCollectionSetting">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="tns:UserSetting">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="WebClientUrls" nillable="true" type="tns:WebClientUrls" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="WebClientUrlCollectionSetting" nillable="true" type="tns:WebClientUrlCollectionSetting" />
  <xs:complexType name="WebClientUrls">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="WebClientUrl" nillable="true" type="tns:WebClientUrl" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="WebClientUrls" nillable="true" type="tns:WebClientUrls" />
  <xs:complexType name="WebClientUrl">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="AuthenticationMethods" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="Url" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="WebClientUrl" nillable="true" type="tns:WebClientUrl" />
  <xs:complexType name="AlternateMailboxCollectionSetting">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="tns:UserSetting">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="AlternateMailboxes" nillable="true" type="tns:AlternateMailboxes" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="AlternateMailboxCollectionSetting" nillable="true" type="tns:AlternateMailboxCollectionSetting" />
  <xs:complexType name="AlternateMailboxes">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="AlternateMailbox" nillable="true" type="tns:AlternateMailbox" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="AlternateMailboxes" nillable="true" type="tns:AlternateMailboxes" />
  <xs:complexType name="AlternateMailbox">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Type" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="DisplayName" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="LegacyDN" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="Server" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="AlternateMailbox" nillable="true" type="tns:AlternateMailbox" />
  <xs:complexType name="ServerVersionInfo">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="MajorVersion" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="MinorVersion" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="MajorBuildNumber" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="MinorBuildNumber" type="xs:int" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Version" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="ServerVersionInfo" nillable="true" type="tns:ServerVersionInfo" />
  <xs:element name="GetDomainSettingsRequestMessage">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Request" nillable="true" type="tns:GetDomainSettingsRequest" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="GetDomainSettingsRequest">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="tns:AutodiscoverRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Domains" nillable="true" type="tns:Domains" />
          <xs:element name="RequestedSettings" nillable="true" type="tns:RequestedSettings" />
          <xs:element name="RequestedVersion" nillable="true" type="tns:ExchangeVersion" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="GetDomainSettingsRequest" nillable="true" type="tns:GetDomainSettingsRequest" />
  <xs:complexType name="Domains">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Domain" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="Domains" nillable="true" type="tns:Domains" />
  <xs:element name="GetDomainSettingsResponseMessage">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Response" nillable="true" type="tns:GetDomainSettingsResponse" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="GetDomainSettingsResponse">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="tns:AutodiscoverResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DomainResponses" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfDomainResponse" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="GetDomainSettingsResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:GetDomainSettingsResponse" />
  <xs:complexType name="ArrayOfDomainResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="DomainResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:DomainResponse" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="ArrayOfDomainResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfDomainResponse" />
  <xs:complexType name="DomainResponse">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="tns:AutodiscoverResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DomainSettingErrors" nillable="true" type="tns:DomainSettingErrors" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DomainSettings" nillable="true" type="tns:DomainSettings" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RedirectTarget" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="DomainResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:DomainResponse" />
  <xs:complexType name="DomainSettingErrors">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="DomainSettingError" nillable="true" type="tns:DomainSettingError" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="DomainSettingErrors" nillable="true" type="tns:DomainSettingErrors" />
  <xs:complexType name="DomainSettingError">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ErrorCode" type="tns:ErrorCode" />
      <xs:element name="ErrorMessage" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="SettingName" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="DomainSettingError" nillable="true" type="tns:DomainSettingError" />
  <xs:complexType name="DomainSettings">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="DomainSetting" nillable="true" type="tns:DomainSetting" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="DomainSettings" nillable="true" type="tns:DomainSettings" />
  <xs:complexType name="DomainSetting">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Name" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="DomainSetting" nillable="true" type="tns:DomainSetting" />
  <xs:complexType name="DomainStringSetting">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="tns:DomainSetting">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Value" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="DomainStringSetting" nillable="true" type="tns:DomainStringSetting" />
  <xs:element name="GetFederationInformationRequestMessage">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Request" nillable="true" type="tns:GetFederationInformationRequest" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="GetFederationInformationRequest">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="tns:AutodiscoverRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Domain" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="GetFederationInformationRequest" nillable="true" type="tns:GetFederationInformationRequest" />
  <xs:element name="GetFederationInformationResponseMessage">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Response" nillable="true" type="tns:GetFederationInformationResponse" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="GetFederationInformationResponse">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="tns:AutodiscoverResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ApplicationUri" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TokenIssuers" nillable="true" type="tns:TokenIssuers" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Domains" nillable="true" type="tns:Domains" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TokenIssuers">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="TokenIssuer" nillable="true" type="tns:TokenIssuer" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="TokenIssuer">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Uri" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Endpoint" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="GetFederationInformationResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:GetFederationInformationResponse" />
  <xs:element name="GetOrganizationRelationshipSettingsRequestMessage">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Request" nillable="true" type="tns:GetOrganizationRelationshipSettingsRequest" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="GetOrganizationRelationshipSettingsRequest">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="tns:AutodiscoverRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Domains" nillable="true" type="tns:Domains" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="GetOrganizationRelationshipSettingsRequest" nillable="true" type="tns:GetOrganizationRelationshipSettingsRequest" />
  <xs:element name="GetOrganizationRelationshipSettingsResponseMessage">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Response" nillable="true" type="tns:GetOrganizationRelationshipSettingsResponse" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="GetOrganizationRelationshipSettingsResponse">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
      <xs:extension base="tns:AutodiscoverResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="OrganizationRelationshipSettingsCollection" nillable="true" type="tns:OrganizationRelationshipSettingsCollection" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="GetOrganizationRelationshipSettingsResponse" nillable="true" type="tns:GetOrganizationRelationshipSettingsResponse" />
  <xs:complexType name="OrganizationRelationshipSettingsCollection">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="OrganizationRelationshipSettings" nillable="true" type="tns:OrganizationRelationshipSettings" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="OrganizationRelationshipSettingsCollection" nillable="true" type="tns:OrganizationRelationshipSettingsCollection" />
  <xs:complexType name="OrganizationRelationshipSettings">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="DeliveryReportEnabled" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element name="DomainNames" nillable="true" type="tns:Domains" /> 
      <xs:element name="FreeBusyAccessEnabled" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element name="FreeBusyAccessLevel" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="MailTipsAccessEnabled" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element name="MailTipsAccessLevel" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="MailboxMoveEnabled" type="xs:boolean" />
      <xs:element name="Name" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />      
      <xs:element name="TargetApplicationUri" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI" />
      <xs:element name="TargetAutodiscoverEpr" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI" />
      <xs:element name="TargetSharingEpr" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="OrganizationRelationshipSettings" nillable="true" type="tns:OrganizationRelationshipSettings" />
</xs:schema>
```